Generate Group total row only for some groups
I am using ag-grid version v27, I have enabled below options to generate total row under each group column:
this.gridOptions.groupIncludeTotalFooter = true;
this.gridOptions.groupIncludeFooter = true;

This generate Total row for all groups, I want to generate total row only for some specific groups.

For New Business, I don't want to show total row. I looked at ag-grid documentation but it's based on new version which is >v30.
